# CLion generating wrong CMake commands

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clion

I have installed CLion on Mac OS High Sierra. My compiler is set to cross compiler *arm-linux-musleabihf-g++*. While in Eclipse I had no problems building binaries I got problem in CLion - CMake generates this issue:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.7/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-musleabihf/6.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-musleabihf/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol arch_paths_first; defaulting to 00000000000100e0
```

I have found that `CMakeFiles/$PROJECTNAME.dir/link.txt` contents invalid link task:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.7/libexec/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-g++  -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -static CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o  -o ../bin/test
```

`-Wl,-search_paths_first` is incorrectly interpreted as Mac OS symbol.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to force CLion or `CMakeLists.txt` to generate correct `link.txt`.